# Can't create a WinRM HTTPS listener on Domain Controllers

Tags: dns, controller, certificate, winrm

I finished deploying WinRM HTTPS on my domain to all computers using a modified webserver certificate template and a GPO. It all works as expected, but not on my DC's. When trying to truobleshoot the issue, my first step was to show listeners using winrm e winrm/config/listener in elevated CMD. This returned the standard HTTP WinRM listener, but no HTTPS listener as all other computers in the domain now have.

Thworing caution at the wind, I tried creating one manually using winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS in elevated CMD.

```
The output was the following:

    C:\Windows\system32>winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The WS-Management service cannot find the certificate that was requested.

Error number:  -2144108414 0x80338082
The WS-Management service cannot find the certificate that was requested.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Strange. I then looked up the certificates on DC01. There were no computer certificates, only those created by the CA (running locallyo n DC01).

[DC01 Certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGMqR.png)

Looking through these CA issues certificates, I noticed that they dono't have a subject. Based on my google-fu, this seems to stick with the "The WS-Management service cannot find the certificate that was requested" error message I got earlier.

The question now is why have WinRM HTTPS certificates been issued to all computers in the domain, the Enable WinRM GPO applied to the Domain controllers, and yet no certificate is being issue to DC01 or DC02 for that matter.

Any and all input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the permissions of your certificate template within the Windows CA. Your computer object needs the permissions "read" and "register" to register a new certificate. Usually the group "Domain Computers" has that right. But Domain Controllers are not part of the group "Domain Computers". So you can add the group "Domain Controllers" to the permision tab and add the permissions "read" and "register".